# Вызов процедуры Oracle из Java

Tags: java, oracle

В базе oracle создан тип

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE coln FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

создана процедура

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (city IN coln)
```

...
Вызывается код

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("test");
    call.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("city", Types.ARRAY, "coln"));

SimpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("city", ??));
```

Какой тип поля нужно передать в SqlParameter? Types.ARRAY
Что нужно передать в addValue?
Пробовал разные варианты, ошибка - некорретный тип поля при вызове процедуры.
Что передавать в addValue?

Из oracle процедура вызывается так

```
begin
    test(coln("city"));
end;
```

Comment: Почему вы создали тип col, а оперируете с типом coln?

Comment: Да вы правы, но это опечатка только в вопросе. Поправил